# includes the jquery library in js of a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to run this ajax work:

```
    $ (document).ready(function() {
 $.ajax({
    url: 'sendvalue.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType:'json', 
    data: ({cookievalue: cookie.value}),
    success: function(data) {
       console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

But, rightfully so, since I have not put in the inclusion of the jquery ajax library (I cannot include because the script is in a js file and not in the index), I get this error:

> index.html:1 Error handling response: ReferenceError: $ is not defined
> at chrome-extension://ebekofgaihoolgeccoalidkchcofecbd/main.js:9:4

I tried to auto-include the library but I get another error:

> main.js:3 Refused to load the script
> 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'
> because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
> "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem:". Note that 'script-src-elem' was
> not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

How can I solve?

Comment: Sounds like a good time to free yourself from the shackles of jQuery :). You can use [the Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to make requests.

Answer (score 0):

Please Remove JS code from your main index file and add new js file and paste code there.
All js and css files included in your index file
And use functionality
I think is work.

Comment: My js is not in the index.html (ie the main index), it is in main.js

Comment: download jQuery file and link as a local file

Comment: <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Unfortunately, working on a chrome extension I have to put some js code only on a js file and I can't put it on the index, so I can't include some html code to include that library even if locally